# How to redirect to a link once item is dropped using jQuery UI?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have a menu

```
             <div id="nav">
     <ul>
        <li><a href="http://www.example.com"> Home </a></li>
        <li><a href="http://www.example.com"> About </a></li>
        <li><a href="http://www.example.com"> Contact </a></li>
      </ul>
                    </div>
```

and a drop zone

```
     <div id="dropzone">
     </div>
```

Once one of the list items is dropped in the dropzone it will then redirect to the link.I am using jQuery UI but I can't figure out how to do this can somebody help me out?

Comment: Show us the JavaScript code. The markup alone is useless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(function(){
    $("#dropzone").droppable(
        {
          drop: function(event, ui){
          window.location.href = ui.draggable.find("a").attr("href");
        }
    });

    $("li").draggable();
});
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/PHU8C/

Answer (score 1):

Use `window.location.href = 'your_link_url';`

Answer (score 1):

You can try it like this

```
$( "#dropzone" ).droppable({
   drop: function(event, ui) { 
       window.location.href = 'http://yourlink.com/';
   }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I've never used either... but maybe you should look at the [documentation](http://jqueryui.com/demos/droppable/)? It seems pretty straightforward. There is a drop event that you can bind to. `$(this)` in the callback is the dropzone.

```
$( ".selector" ).droppable({
   drop: function(event, ui) { 
       window.location.href = $(this).attr("href");
   }
});
```